R3F raycast hits wrong object
this is the code to generate buffergeometries:
  const boxList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  const depth = 0.1;
  const width = 0.017;

  <Splat
    position={[0, 0, 0]}
    src={URL}
  />

  <CameraControls
    makeDefault
  />
  {boxList.map((i) => {
    const v1 = [-0.075 + i * width, 0.06, 0];
    const v2 = [-0.075, 0.06, -depth];
    const v3 = [
      -0.075 + (i + 1) * width,
      0.06,
      -depth,
    ];
    const v4 = [
      -0.075 + (i + 1) * width,
      0.06,
      0,
    ];

    const v5 = [v1[0], 0.15, v1[2]];
    const v6 = [v2[0], 0.15, v2[2]];
    const v7 = [v3[0], 0.15, v3[2]];
    const v8 = [v4[0], 0.15, v4[2]];

    const vertices = new Float32Array([
      //bottom
      ...v1,
      ...v2,
      ...v3,

      ...v3,
      ...v4,
      ...v1,

      //top
      ...v5,
      ...v6,
      ...v7,

      ...v7,
      ...v8,
      ...v5,

      //north
      ...v1,
      ...v4,
      ...v5,

      ...v4,
      ...v5,
      ...v8,

      //east
      ...v1,
      ...v2,
      ...v5,

      ...v5,
      ...v6,
      ...v2,

      //south
      ...v2,
      ...v3,
      ...v6,

      ...v6,
      ...v7,
      ...v3,

      //west
      ...v3,
      ...v4,
      ...v7,

      ...v7,
      ...v8,
      ...v4,
    ]);

    return (
      <mesh
        key={i}
        onPointerMove={(e) => {
          console.log(e.object.id);
        }}
      >
        <bufferGeometry>
          <bufferAttribute
            attach="attributes-position"
            array={vertices}
            count={vertices.length / 3}
            itemSize={3}
          />
        </bufferGeometry>
        <meshBasicMaterial
          transparent={true}
          opacity={0.1}
          color={0xff0000}
          side={2}
        />
      </mesh>
    );
  })}
  <Preload all />

Now the issue is that when hovering the mouse over the same object, it returns different Ids!!

How can I intersect the buffer geometries using the raycast in R3F?
Regards
By the way, it will be cool if you could add some insights on how to raycast to the splat object
